# `getParseData` yields different results in `interactive()` vs Rscript

Tags: r, nse

Please see the below MWE

```r
generate_summ_code= function(...) {
  code = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  gpd = getParseData(parse(text = deparse(code)), includeText = TRUE)
  print(gpd)
  gpd
}

generate_summ_code(n = n())
```

If I run that in REPL I get the print out

```
>    line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent                token terminal  text
> 10     1    1     1    5 10      0                 expr    FALSE n()()
> 6      1    1     1    3  6     10                 expr    FALSE   n()
> 1      1    1     1    1  1      3 SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL     TRUE     n
> 3      1    1     1    1  3      6                 expr    FALSE     n
> 2      1    2     1    2  2      6                  '('     TRUE     (
> 4      1    3     1    3  4      6                  ')'     TRUE     )
> 7      1    4     1    4  7     10                  '('     TRUE     (
> 8      1    5     1    5  8     10                  ')'     TRUE     )
```

However, if I put the code inside a file say `code.r` and I do

`Rscript code.r`

or

`R -e "source('code.r')"`

It just returns NULL. There is nothing in the `?getParseData` that indicates that the behaviour should be different?

Is this a bug in Base R?

Comment: For what it’s worth, `force(code)` has no effect here.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in interactive mode the `keep.source` option is set to `TRUE`, otherwise it is set to `FALSE` (unless you override it). Therefore, the behaviour of `parse` differs:

```
〉getParseData(parse(text = '1 + 1'), includeText = TRUE)
  line1 col1 line2 col2 id parent     token terminal  text
7     1    1     1    5  7      0      expr    FALSE 1 + 1
1     1    1     1    1  1      2 NUM_CONST     TRUE     1
2     1    1     1    1  2      7      expr    FALSE     1
3     1    3     1    3  3      7       '+'     TRUE     +
4     1    5     1    5  4      5 NUM_CONST     TRUE     1
5     1    5     1    5  5      7      expr    FALSE     1
〉getParseData(parse(text = '1 + 1', keep.source = FALSE), includeText = TRUE)
NULL
```

Comment: Yeah. I just figured that independently. Is that documented somewhere or have I just missed it?

Comment: @xiaodai Yes, itʼs in the “description” section of the [`getParseData` documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/getParseData.html).

Comment: "If the "keep.source" option is TRUE, R's parser will attach detailed information on the object it has parsed. These functions retrieve that information." But it doesn't say that in interactive mode keep.source is set differently. Or is that meant to be "common" knowledge?

Comment: @xiaodai Ah, right. The standard R options are all documented [on the page of the `option` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html).